How to list components of other module in Angular 13?
I created in my project simple module with one component to test.
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ButtonComponent} from "@modules/basic-components/components/button/button.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class BasicComponentsModule {}

And in component of other module i want to list components of my BasicComponentsModule.
I'm trying load module like this:
const module = await import('@modules/basic-components/basic-components.module');

When i'm logging module i see in Chrome dev tools that it has all what i need:

But how i can module declarations from code? Also i need to get a list of inputs for each component.
Upd. I tried to use Reflect methods like getMetadata and getOwnMetadata:
const module = await import('@modules/basic-components/basic-components.module');

const moduleMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata('__annotations__', module.BasicComponentsModule);
const declarations = moduleMetadata[0].declarations;

But i'm always getting undefined in moduleMetadata for my module. What is the problem?
